# How to prevent other elements from highlighting when dragging any devexpress component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-chrome, devexpress

Just updated my devexpress version to 12.1 and now all draggable elements hightlights background elements on Chrome (20.0.1132.47 m).

For example when I drag splitter all page is blinking, when I'm dragging ASPxPivotGrid or ASPxGridView field, field sometimes highlights and nearby elements highlights then I drag past them. In ASPxGridview when I'm re-sizing columns and if I move my mouse a little bit to up or down almost all header highlights. There are also unneeded highlight when I'm dragging fields in ASPxPivotGrid customization form..

BTW, in IE9, FF11, Opera 11.6 and it works fine.

Is it devexpress bug? How can I fix it so dragging would not highlight background elements? Maybe some kinda global jquery function would help?

Comment: With "highlighting" do you mean the background elements get selected? If so, you could try `$(document).on("selectstart", false)` and `.off` to prevent selections during dragging. (I've no experience with devexpress, though.)

Comment: @pimvdb Yes, I mean they get selected. And yes, `$(document).on("selectstart", false)` and `.off()` does work very good, now I just have to find the way when I should call them.
P.S. Why you wrote a comment not a answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent selections in the whole document using:

```
$(document).on("selectstart", false);
```

You can enable selections again by removing that event handler:

```
$(document).off("selectstart", false);
```

You could disable selections during `mousedown` on an element, and enable it again during `mouseup`. It doesn't matter where the user triggers `mouseup`, so attach that one to `document`: http://jsfiddle.net/Wdj6w/.

```
$("div").on("mousedown", function() {
  $(document).on("selectstart", false);
});

$(document).on("mouseup", function() {
  $(document).off("selectstart", false);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up adding this function calling to all grids on EndCallback:  
`function fixchrome() {
if ($.browser.safari) {
$(".dxpgHeader_DevEx,.dxsplVSeparator_DevEx,.dxgvHeader_DevEx").on("mousedown", function () {
$(document).on("selectstart", false);
});
};
}`

Comment: @Bomberlt: Are you sure? That will bind the handler again and again, and doesn't remove it.

Comment: Oh, yes I forgot to add .off() too :)

Answer (score -1):

You can also prevent selection via CSS's `user-select` property. Like so:

```
 <div style="-webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none;">
   <p>I cannot be selected</p>
 </div>
```

See [this css-tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/)